# Where can I set Access-Type of client as "bearer-only" in the new keycloak admin console?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

In older versions of keycloak, the Access-Type of a client can be set in **Settingｓ** tab as follows

[image]

But in keycloak version 20.0.1, there is no Access type field in the client Settings tab as follows:

[image]

Where can I set **Access-Type** of the client with keycloak 20.0.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As one can read on the following groups.google.com keycloak threads:

- https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user/c/75iuKmiYvBU
- https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-dev/c/dvgDVYn1P2E/m/VjkFF2DUAQAJ?pli=1

> **Stian Thorgersen** Mar 3, 2021, 10:49:03 AM to Keycloak Dev
>
> The new admin console designs are dropping the "bearer-only" option for a
> client:
>
> https://marvelapp.com/prototype/908c3c3/screen/72041413
>
> This makes perfectly sense to me, as a "bearer-only" client is really
> only a client that doesn't leverage any of the OAuth flows.

The option of explicitly setting the `access-type` of clients to `bearer-only` is not longer available on the new Keycloak Admin Console UI. Nonetheless, with the new UI one can still see clients that were previously (in older versions) created with `access-type` `bearer-only`. However, one cannot change their `access-type`.

Even though the new UI does not have the option to explicitly set the `access-type` to `bearer-only`, one can still create an equivalent `bearer-only` client by unchecking all the Authentications flows, as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using keycloak v 21.0.1
I tried the accepted answer but got this error.
[image]

tweaking it a little bit by checking direct access grants got me the desired result - getting access and refresh token without secret key

[image]

This is a trial and error approach, so someone with substantial knowledge can comment with any official reference.